# IEnumerable data type: how to create a null object?

Tags: c#, object, null, ienumerable

I have an object with several IEnumerable collections:

```
public class Product
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    IEnumerable<CrossSell> CrossSells {get;set;}
    IEnumerable<UpSell> UpSells {get;set;}
    IEnumerable<PricePromos> PricePromos {get;set;}
}
```

I need to create a null object (all properties are blank but not null).
Apparently, I cannot just create an Enumerable item.

Other than creating an entirely new class, how could I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Empty<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042.aspx) or just a new, zero-length array.

Answer (score 0):

As cdhowie suggests, a zero-element array will work just as well. The syntax is `new T[0]`.